# How to use $nin operator with objects in array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I've made a simplified collection to show my problem:

```
  db.testcol.insert({ a: 1, msgs: [ { listname: "list1", someinfo: "info"}, { listname: "list2", someinfo: "info"}]});
db.testcol.insert({ a: 1, msgs: [ { listname: "list2", someinfo: "info"}]});
db.testcol.insert({ a: 1, msgs: [ { listname: "list3", someinfo: "info"}]});
db.testcol.insert({ a: 1, msgs: [ { listname: "list4", someinfo: "info"}]});
db.testcol.insert({ a: 1, msgs: [ ]});
db.testcol.insert({ a: 2 });
```

I need to get all documents from this collection which DOES NOT CONTAIN object with field listname: "list1" in array msgs, in other words I need all docs except first. I have problem with this query, I think I should use $nin operator but I can't find any example how to use it with objects. I've tried queries like this:

```
db.testcol.find({ "msgs.listName": { "$nin":[ "list1" ] } }).pretty()
db.testcol.find({ "msgs": { "$nin":[ { listName: "list1" } ] } }).pretty()
```

but all of them doen't work as i need I still can't get the right result. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an quite common mistake.

In your collection, the field is named `listname` (note the lowercase) whereas in your query the field is name `listName` (note the camel case). Field names are case sensitive. so when adjusting the first query to

```
db.testcol.find({ "msgs.listname": { "$nin":[ "list1" ] } }).pretty()
```

you get the expected result.

**EDIT**

As @NeilLunn correctly pointed out in the comments, the better approach when ruling out a **single** value as per the question would be:

```
db.testcol.find({ "msgs.listname": { "$ne": "list1" } })
```

This approach is both cleaner and faster when just a single value needs to be ruled out.

All kudos to him.

Comment: Thanks it a really stupid mistake i thought problem was with query(((

Comment: @DmitryMalugin While the other answer given here was incorrect in it's assumptions there was one valid point not addressed. You don't need operators like `$nin` or `$in` to work on an array element within a document. Simply `db.testcol.find({ "msgs.listname": { "$ne": "list1" } })` is sufficient. `$nin` and `$in` are meant to be supplied an "array of arguments" themselves. So it it an almost useless use of the operator with a single argument. The "array" applies to arguments, not the content of the document.

Comment: @NeilLunn: Right you are, as always. Especially since `$nin` is much worth performance wise.

Comment: Thank a lot guys, I'll follow your advises

Answer (score -2):

```
db.testcol.find({'msgs.0.listname':{'$ne':'list1'}})
```

Comment: This query is not very robust, is it?

Comment: Sometimes speed is better than robustness. Thanks for the -